# elasticSearch: how to query with collapse

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to get a query result with two different part,

- query docs with field X and collapse on it.
- query docs without field X
- pagination based on queries above

For example, I have docs:

| docID | Field X |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | b |

There are 4 docs, doc 1 and 2 have same X value, doc 3 have no value at X, doc 4 have unique value.

So the target docs should be (1 or 2), 3 and 4, and I need to add pagination condition (from + size)here

Is there any way to do this? now I have a collapse query but can only get doc(1 or 2)

```
GET job_info/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "total": {
       "cardinality": {
           "field": "x.keyword"
       }
     }
   },
  "collapse": {
     "field": "x.keyword"
   },
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
             "other_condition1": [
                  1101
              ]
           }
        },
        {
          "match": {
             "other_condition1": {
                 "query": "abc"
              }
          }
         }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```